# interface definition in typescript

Tags: typescript

```
interface Entry {
  fn: Function,
  id?: number,
  recur?: number
}

interface Schedule {
  [tick: number]: Entry[]
}
```

Defination of interface in typescript is not the same as in java. I can't understand this line: `[tick: number]: Entry[]`.
Can you tell me what's it mean?

Answer (score 0):

that definition seems to be an indexer property that can be used as:

```
let a: Schedule = {};
a[5] = anEntryArray;   // succeeds
a["5"] = anEntryArray; // fails
a[5] = "a string";     // fails
```